# Stop echo of commands on ubuntu startup

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

**How do I stop the echo of commands on ubuntu startup ?**

An image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Ubuntu Desktop normally shows a splash screen during boot up, but for some reason (or perhaps an installation issue), in my PC, it shows a verbose list of messages in text mode.

**May I fix this without reinstalling ubuntu?**

---

**Now I'm sure the origin of the problem is this:**

- I installed Windows and, since the boot-loader was modified with no dual boot available, I created a new GRUB file using Puppy Linux Live CD (FAST AN EASY SOLUTION). Almost everything  ok, except the problem I'm stating here. Any ideas about how to fix it?
- Grub File (produced by Puppy Linux):

  ```
  # menu.lst produced by grub4dosconfig-v1.9.2
  color white/green yellow/blue white/black green/black
  #splashimage=/splash.xpm
  timeout 10
  default 0

  # Full installed Linux

  title Ubuntu
    uuid 4a0cefa3-46a8-4143-8fbd-1872c641c9a4
    kernel /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro
    initrd /initrd.img

  # Windows
  # this entry searches Windows on the HDD and boot it up
  title Windows\nBoot up Windows if installed
    errorcheck off
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd  /bootmgr
    chainloader /bootmgr
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd  /ntldr
    chainloader /ntldr
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies --ignore-cd   /io.sys
    chainloader /io.sys
    errorcheck on

  # Advanced Menu
  title Advanced menu
    configfile /menu-advanced.lst
    commandline
  ```

Comment: do you have `plymouth` installed?

Comment: [ravery](https://askubuntu.com/users/694267/ravery): do you have plymouth installed?   -- I guess not.  I don't know what is that

Comment: Normally it should show a purplish screen with blinking dots and the Ubuntu logo at boot (which is provided by the Plymouth application). I am not sure though if it automatically switches to the boot log output if there are any start jobs timing out like on your screenshot. Can you show the content of your `/etc/default/grub` file please? Also we should diagnose that start job, so please add the output of `systemctl status dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-d9bc` (press the TAB key to autocomplete the rest of the name) as well.

Comment: please see [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/q/248/283843). you may also need to  `sudo update-grub` to replace the Putty Linux grub. Or refer to [How can I repair grub?](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/283843).

Comment: [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander):  This has happened to me in two different machines and in My Machine, before this happened,  the contents  of **/etc/default/grub**  was exactly the same to that of the other machine with the problem. So I think there's nothing to look for there.  Regarding to the 'start job' ... I don't have that problem in My Machine and by the moment I don't have access to the other machine. I'm sorry. I'm providing in the question more information about the origin of the problem. But I still don't know the solution.

Comment: [αғsнιη](https://askubuntu.com/users/283843/%ce%b1%d2%93s%d0%bd%ce%b9%ce%b7): **sudo update-grub** doesn't work. Everything keeps the same.  I'm going to work now. Later I'm going to try to follow the [How can I repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/283843) article, which seems to be a little bit complex (compared to the **Puppy** Linux solution) Perhaps I should search for a solution to this in a Puppy Linux forum.

Comment: That grub file is completely different from the grub file in a standard Ubuntu install.  So I'm guessing you have a very different version of grub, and the standard Ubuntu answer (which is very simple) is not going to help you, unless you install the standard Ubuntu version of grub.

Comment: From what I can tell, puppy uses grub and Ubuntu uses grub2.

Comment: @αғsнιη Please, post your answer. I solved the problem using the second answer in the article you suggested.

Comment: @ShirleyTemple You mean you used `Esc` key to exit from text mode, or you used [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/283843)?

Comment: @αғsнιη boot-repair.  As simple as Puppy Linux solution.

Comment: @ShirleyTemple Well! `boot-repair` does the same with [what accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/283843) does but in GUI. if it's complex [here is my this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/525658/283843) with less complex and since you are able to boot your Ubuntu now so  [`ravery's answer`](https://askubuntu.com/a/963621/283843) also shortest. You can vote the answer which answers your question + accept that :  )

Comment: @Byte Commander  This is the output you asked:  ~$ systemctl status dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-d9bcf651\\x2d1c04\\x2d4247\\x2dabe6\\x2d240549228494.
● dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d9bcf651\x2d1c04\x2d4247\x2dabe6\x2d240549228494..service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)   -> sorry for the delay. This machine is in the house of my brother. Not access to it daily. This is a second problem not related with the main problem in this post. But I'd like to understand and solved it also.. Thanks.

Comment: @ShirleyTemple You seem to have a device configured to mount on boot in your `/etc/fstab` by UUID which no longer exists (maybe because it was formatted, which changes the UUID). Please post a new question with that output you mentioned above (`systemctl status dev-disk-by...`), the content of your `/etc/fstab` file and the output of `lsblk -f`. You can ping me here again with a link and I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well at the moment you are using puppy linux's grub4dos to boot

You need to reinstall Ubuntu's grub.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda  #if booting in legacy mode
```

or

```
sudo install-grub  #if booting in EFI mode
```

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `grub-install` instead of `install-grub`?

Comment: @Nusry -- both work on most distros, but I'll switch it to match grub documentation