# I have deleted swap partition and logged out of system 8n Ubuntu.. please help me to turn it again

Tags: boot, swap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQDWN.jpg)

I have tried by adding noresume also....

Comment: What Ubuntu flavor and version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.4 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleted swap partition. Now it is booting to grub rescue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525592/deleted-swap-partition-now-it-is-booting-to-grub-rescue)

Comment: I have no dual boot system

Comment: It looks like you may have set up hibernate in your computer in the past. Hibernate uses swap partition. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423068/edit) and add all the new information such as Ubuntu version, dual boot, hibernate set up you used, etc.